# Detect inline/floated element being pushed to new line

Tags: css, css-float

I'm currently wondering about the following problem: I have for example a simple header H1 with a SPAN tag inside which I want to style differently by CSS depending on the position of the SPAN element, meaning I need to detect if the span element is in line with the text node content of the H1 tag or is pushed to a new line because it doesn't fit in the line.

```html
<h1>
  This is a header
  <span class="special">Special content</span>
</h1>
```

Is there anybody out there having a good idea or even a solution to this?

Comment: in css file add this line h1 span{ your styles }

Comment: So if I didn't misunderstand you, do you mean that you want to detect when the span goes to a new line?

Comment: Why do you want to style it differently? Can you give us a better idea of the effect you want to accomplish?

Comment: thanks, but i need to style h1 span {} dependent on the fact wether or not the span is pushed to a new line. e.g. if we have a pseudo selector h1 span:newline i could set different styles for h1 span {} and h1 span:newline {}

Comment: I want to style the span differently because e.g. in case it fits in one line with the h1 text content I show it as a label with smaller font-size and left margin to separate it from the text. And in case the span ist pushed to a new line I would like to give it a top-margin and no left-margin and maybe another font-size ;) its tricky

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript

Just use javascript to add/remove class if element is or is not wrapped.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsu2ddem/)

### CSS

But if you really want to use just css then you can try with this problematic solution:

Use `::first-line` pseudo element to style **header** and then style span as rest of `h1`. The problem is that it could style also your header if it would wrap at some point.

```css
h1::first-line {
    color: black;
}
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  This is a header
  <span class="special">Special content</span>
</h1>
```

Sadly, CSS does not have any complex mechanism for managing lines.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a good approach! It only does not work in case the h1 text content spreads across two or more lines. Again, thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Steven Just like I said. That's why I strongly suggest using javascript for this rather than forcing css to do what it was not meant to do.